# Search a string for an occurrence of characters of other string

Tags: xcode, nsstring, nsscanner, cfstring

I have two NSString, for example: stringOne = @"1760254913042013"; stringTwo = @"4917602549030391";

I need to compare both strings to find out if both have some string in common. In the example this common string would be @"17602549". Trying to avoid writing some specific code, I been searching in NSScanner, CFString, NSString methods but nothing seems to solve this problem.
Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two strings have many strings in common, such as `"30"`, `"91"`, and every substring of `"17602549"`. It appears you're looking for the *longest* substring that two strings have in common.

Google "Objective-C longest common substring", and you'll find [this method on Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Objective-C).